# Why wont my footer stick ?

Tags: html, css, footer

I want to stick my footer to the very bottom of the page without spacing so it show the same on every screen.

This is how it looks currently:

http://www.slyfiles.com/login.php

Footer code:

```
<div class="footer">
<div class="container">
<span id="footer"> &copy; 2012 SlyFiles &nbsp;<a href="#">About</a>  &nbsp<a     href="#">TOS</a>  &nbsp<a href="#">DMCA</a>  </span>
</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.footer {
background: #1d1d1d;
width: 100%;
height: 32px;
border-top: solid 10px #017cc5;
margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Why won't it stick to bottom?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS for `.footer`:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/bottom-footer-demo.htm

Answer (score 0):

Add clear:both also.

```
.footer{
clear:both;
}
```

I have followed http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/